# convert hex values to decimal in a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
RAM_SIZE 3128
RAM_ADDRESS_WIDTH 0xF
MTFE 0xF
IPS_ADDR_WIDTH 314
```

I want to convert hex values to decimal and display something like:

```
RAM_SIZE 3128
RAM_ADDRESS_WIDTH 15
MTFE 15
IPS_ADDR_WIDTH 314
```

I tried with awk:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
  if ($2 == "0x*")
    printf "%s %d \n", $1, $3 ;
  else 
    print $1 " " $2 
}
```

Not able to use wildcards properly in if case.

I also wanted to use sed, but I don't know how to use column numbers in a sed expression :

```
sed -e 's/0x*/$(($2))/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-n` tells GNU awk to work on non-decimal data:

```
$ gawk -n '{$2+=0}1' file        
RAM_SIZE 3128
RAM_ADDRESS_WIDTH 15
MTFE 15
IPS_ADDR_WIDTH 314
```

wrt your statement `Not able to use wildcards properly in if case.`, you wrote:

```
if ($2 == "0x*")
```

where

```
"0x*" is a STRING containing the characters "0", "x", and "*".
== is the STRING comparison operator.
```

What you wanted though was a regexp comparison, not a string one, so you should have started by writing:

```
if ($2 ~ /0x*/)
```

since:

```
/0x*/ is a REGEXP that means `0 then x repeated zero or more times`
~ is the REGEXP comparison operator
```

but I suspect you don't really want the `*` and what you actually intended was:

```
if ($2 ~ /^0x/)
```

since:

```
/^0x/ is a REGEXP that means `starting with 0 and followed by x`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu-awk it is pretty simple:

```
awk '{print $1, strtonum($2)}' file
RAM_SIZE 3128
RAM_ADDRESS_WIDTH 15
MTFE 15
IPS_ADDR_WIDTH 314
```